# directives for indian phone number is not working in angular 8

Tags: angular

I have created following angular custom directive, it is working fine if we using numbers above alphabets, but is it not working if we used numpad of keyboard.

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appIndianphonenumber]'
})

export class IndianphonenumberDirective {

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

    @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        const pattern = /[0-9\+\-\ ]/;
        const inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);

        if (event.keyCode != 8 && !pattern.test(inputChar)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    @HostListener('blur', ['$event']) blur(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        this.el.nativeElement.value = this.el.nativeElement.value.slice(0, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you press the NumLock key on the number pad first? :)

Comment: Yes, i have pressed numlock key